# How do I find a document with the method findone from @nestjs/typeorm?

Tags: mongodb, typeorm

First off, I do an api with nest, graphql, typeorm with database mongo. **Graphql works well by the way**, I said you the problem that for the Id. The cause that I have created a models named Item with the next specifications. I can create, findAll documents but I can not find a document with the id

```
@Entity('Item')
@ObjectType()
export class Item {
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  @Field(() => ID)
  id: ObjectID;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
  name?: string;

  @Column()
  @Field(() => Float)
  quantity: number;

  @Column()
  @Field(() => String)
  quantityUnits: string;

  @Field()
  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

Also, I have added a function where use a service for find one document. @Query is for Graphql by the way.

```
@Query(() => Item, { name: 'item' })
  async findOne(@Args('id', { type: () => ID }) id: string): Promise<Item> {
    const results = await this.itemsService.findOne(id);

    return results;
  }
```

That is service where query to the database Mongo. I have changed the query with other parameters with name, quantity and the service does well but with id return null, but the document exists.

```
async findOne(id: string) {
    try {
      const results = await this.destinationsRepository.findOne({
        where: { id },
      });

      if (isEmpty(results)) throw new Error('Email is already in use');

      return results;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error ===', error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use findOneBy so it would look like this:

```
  async findOne(id: number) {
    try {
      const results = await this.destinationsRepository.findOneBy({
        id: id,
      });

      if (isEmpty(results)) throw new Error('Email is already in use');

      return results;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error ===', error);
    }
  }
```

Also check your type, it should be number unless you have some sort of custom override in your dto????

Comment: I did it. I changed the query like Where: {id: id} and the types. The query returns null too. You are right. I checked the types. There is an example like define models. [link](https://typeorm.io/mongodb#mongodb-support) .

Comment: Are you able to use findOneBy https://typeorm.io/